# twitter gem not working in heroku?

Tags: ruby, twitter, heroku

I'm working on a ruby app that updates a twitter account using 'twitter' gem. It's working fine locally (as usual :) ). But when I deploy it on heroku it seems the gem is not properly installed or something lile that as I got the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Twitter::OAuth
```

My code is very simple:

```
oauth = Twitter::OAuth.new(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
oauth.authorize_from_access(access_token, access_secret)
client = Twitter::Base.new(oauth)
client.update("Updating my status from twitter gem.  GREAT!")
```

Is there a problem with this particular gem ?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Luc

Comment: You may want to check to see if the gem versions installed locally and in production are the same. e.g. `gem list | grep twitter` or puts Twitter::VERSION on both to confirm that they're the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created a .gems file and put `twitter` in it?

Depending on which heroku 'stack' you are on, you may need to do that instead of a bundler Gemfile. You can change your stack for one that uses bundler by doing this:

```
heroku stack:migrate bamboo-ree-1.8.7
```

Which makes bundler available (I think).

Comment: hello, yes I did this but I realized that the version was not the correct one. I had 0.9.12 locally where version 1.0.0 was installed on heroku. I then had to specify 'twitter --version 0.9.12' in my .gems file and it's working then.

Answer (score 1):

That is a common message that usually implies that you have a discrepancy between your local gems and the gems in heroku. If you are not using Bundler yet, you should. You will end un writing a very simple Gemfile that will tell Heroku (or any other entity using your code) which gems and versions you require.

http://gembundler.com/

Comment: Hello, I still use .gems file as I am not familiar with the bundle way. I should give it a try, your right.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should use the heroku addon called 'apigee', ut makes twitter on heroku simple:

http://addons.heroku.com/apigee

Answer (score 0):

I just got a sinatra app talking to Twitter through Heroku/Apigee, my rate limit went from 300 calls per hour to 20,000 calls per hour. Here's a step by step on what to do:

http://geeks.aretotally.in/mind/2011/1/8/increasing-api-limits-on-a-sinatra-twitter-app-with-twitter_.html

I am really a Java developer just playing around with Sinatra but let me know if I can help in anything.

Felipe

Comment: Hey Luc did it work for you? You can also see a full app at https://github.com/feliperazeek/Paparazzi-on-Tweets.

Comment: @Felipe Oliveira did you have to pay anything to Apigee to get this rate limit increase?